# Download large file using spring's AbstractXlsxView

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring's AbstractXlsxView to download a large file.
Below is how the code for AbstractXlsxView implementation and controller method looks like.

```
class ExcelView extends AbstractXlsxView {

@Override
protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> map, Workbook workbook, 
     HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception { 
    //logic here...
}}
```

---

```
class ExportController {

@PostMapping("/report.xlsx")
public View downloadReport() throws SQLException {
        ExcelView view = exportDataService.getReport();
        return view;
}}
```

I am facing **heap outOfMemory** error with large files (~1GB) with this approach. Is there any way I can modify this approach to accommodate large files (writing to output stream rather than having everything in memory) ?